# How can I produce this circuit on Latex?

Tags: circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib

I have no idea how to do a circuit with "off" itens like the  S2 IGBT and diode D1 below. anyone can help me ?

### Here is My Code

```
  \documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    every pin/.style = {pin distance=7mm, inner sep=1pt, text=teal,
        pin edge={teal, line width=2pt, shorten <=-2pt, 
            {Triangle Cap[]}-{Circle[open,line width=1pt,length=1.6mm]}}
    },
}
\ctikzset{resistor = european} %Definição de uso do resitor europeu


\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages,scale=1.25][european resistors]

        \draw
        (0,3) to[open,-*, l_=$V_{1}$] (0,0) %% Criação da Fonte
        ;  %% Finalizando plotagem da fonte


        \draw 
        (0,3) to[L, *-, l^=$L$, f^=$i_{L}$] (3,3) coordinate (Qpos) % conectando um indutor do ponto 0,2 até o 3,2 (Tamanho3)
        (5,3) coordinate (Qpos1)
        (7,3) coordinate (Qpos2)

        (Qpos)++(0,-3)
        to[Tnigbt, bodydiode] ++(0,3)

        (Qpos)        
        to[Tnigbt,bodydiode] ++(3,0)

        (Qpos1)++(1,-3)
        to[C, -,f_<=$i_{C}$,l^=$C_{DC}$] ++(0,3) coordinate (LMpos)

        (Qpos2)++(0.5,-3) coordinate (Rpos)
        to[open,*-*,l_=$V_{2}$] ++(0,3) -- (LMpos) %Se usado o Parametro V<= teriamos o + e - da tensão. Ao contrário disso foi usado l de label

        (Rpos) --(0,0)  
        (3.8,1.5) node[align=center]{$D_1$}
        (2.1,1.5) node[align=center]{$G_1$}
        (4.55,3.8) node[align=center]{$G_2$}
        (4.55,2.4) node[align=center]{$D_2$}
        (0,0) to[short,-*] (3,0)

        ;

    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

### My Result

[image]

### The Result I desire

[image: Circuit Figure]

Comment: opacity=0.5 comes to mind.  color=lightgray also might work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sorry @dexteritas I'll update the post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**edit:** in the first attemt i upload wrong image and code. now this is corrected :-)

like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                }
\ctikzset{resistor = european} %Definição de uso do resitor europeu
\tikzset{B/.style = {decorate,   % added
            decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt,
            raise=3pt, mirror},thick},
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[
american voltages,scale=1.25][european resistors]
\draw
    (0,0)                                                   coordinate (in+)
                to [L=$L$, f^=$i_{L}$,o-*]  ++  (2,0)       coordinate (T1+)
                -- ++  (0,-0.5)
                node [nigbt,anchor=D]  (igbt1) {}
    (igbt1.G)   -- ++ (0,-0.5) node[below] {$S_1$}
    (igbt1.G)   -- ++ (0,-0.5) node[below] {$S_1$}
    (igbt1.S)   to [short,-*]               ++  (0,-0.5)    coordinate (T1-)
    (T1+)       -- ++  (0.5,0)
                node [nigbt,anchor=S,rotate=-90,color=gray]  (igbt2) {}
    (igbt2.D)   to [short, -*]               ++  (0.5,0)     coordinate (C+)
                to [C,a=$C_{DC}$,f=$i_{C}$,*-*]  (C+ |- T1-)
    (C+)        to [short, -o]               ++  (1.0,0)    coordinate (out+)
    (out+ |- T1-)                                           coordinate (out-)
    (in+ |- out-)                                           coordinate (in-)
    (in-)       to [short,o-]   (T1-)
                to [short,-o]   (out-);
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=6mm}
\draw       (igbt2.S)   -- ++ (0,-0.3) coordinate (D2)
                        to [Do,a=D2] (D2 -| igbt2.D) -- (igbt2.D);
\draw[gray] (igbt2.G) -- ++ (-0.5,0) node[left,gray] {$S_2$}
            (igbt1.S) -- ++ (0.3,0)  coordinate (D1)
                      to [Do,a=D1,color=gray] (D1 |- igbt1.D) -- (igbt1.D);
\draw[B]    (in+)  -- node[ left=5pt] {$V_1$} (in-);
\draw[B]    (out-) -- node[right=5pt] {$V_2$} (out+);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:**

- coloring elements in `circuitikz` is simple. you only need to add option `color=<selected color>` between element options. for example, IGBT `igbt2` in the above example is in the gray color:

  ```
  ... node [nigbt,anchor=S,rotate=-90, color=gray] ...
  ```
- for coloring complete branches, for example for diode D1 inthe  above example, you need this branch draw separately:

  ```
   ...     
   \draw[gray] 
   (igbt2.G) -- ++ (-0.5,0) node[left,gray] {$S_2$}% node with IGBT control input, in gray color
   (igbt1.S) -- ++ (0.3,0)  coordinate (D1)                
             to [Do,a=D1,color=gray] (D1 |- igbt1.D) 
             -- (igbt1.D);                         % diode at igbt2 in gray color
   ...
  ```
- a complete example with semiconductor elements in state "on" in red color together with connection lines  is shown in example below. its code is a bit different from the above example:

  - branches in circuit are reorganized and divided regarding of their colors
  - styles of the elements are determined globally
  - diode size are determined at begin of the circuit scheme

    ```
    \documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage[siunitx,american]{circuitikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                    calc,
                    decorations.pathreplacing,
                    }
    \ctikzset{resistor = european,  %Definição de uso do resitor europeu
              voltage = american}
    \tikzset{B/.style = {decorate,
                decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt,
                raise=3pt, mirror},thick},
            }

    \begin{document}
        \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.25],
    \ctikzset{bipoles/diode/height=0.25,bipoles/diode/width=0.25}
    \draw
    (0,0)                                                   coordinate (in+)
                to [L=$L$, f^=$i_{L}$,o-]  ++  (2,0)        coordinate (T1+);
    \draw[red]                                                  % branch in red color
    (T1+)       to [short,*-] ++  (0,-0.5)
                node [nigbt,anchor=D, color=red]  (igbt1) {}    % IGBT as node, in red color
    (igbt1.G)   -- ++ (0,-0.5) node[below] {$S_1$}              % node with IGBT control input
    (igbt1.S)   to [short,-*]               ++  (0,-0.5)    coordinate (T1-);
    \draw % black again
    (T1+)       ++  (0.5,0)                                 % no line to IGBT
                node [nigbt,anchor=S,
                      rotate=-90,color=gray]  (igbt2) {}    % IGBT as node, in gray color
    (igbt2.D)   ++  (0.5,0)                                 coordinate (C+);
    \draw[red]
    (T1+)       to[short,*-]              (igbt2.S)         % red line to IGBT
                -- ++ (0,-0.3) coordinate (D2)              % red line to diode
                to [Do,a=D2,color=red] (D2 -| igbt2.D)      % diode, in red color
                -- (igbt2.D)                                % red line to IOGBT
                to [short,-*] (C+);                         % red line from IGBT to C
    \draw % black again
    (C+)        to [C,a=$C_{DC}$,f>^=$i_{C}$,*-*]  (C+ |- T1-)
    (C+)        to [short, -o]               ++  (1.0,0)    coordinate (out+)
    (out+ |- T1-)                                           coordinate (out-)
    (in+ |- out-)                                           coordinate (in-)
    (in-)       to [short,o-]   (T1-)
                to [short,-o]   (out-);
    %
    \draw[gray] (igbt2.G) -- ++ (-0.5,0) node[left,gray] {$S_2$}% node with IGBT control input, in gray color
                (igbt1.S) -- ++ (0.3,0)  coordinate (D1)
                          to [Do,a=D1,color=gray] (D1 |- igbt1.D)
                          -- (igbt1.D);                         % diode at igbt2 in gray color
    %
    \draw[B]    (in+)  -- node[ left=5pt] {$V_1$} (in-);        % curly brace indicated input
    \draw[B]    (out-) -- node[right=5pt] {$V_2$} (out+);       % curly brace indicated output
        \end{circuitikz}
    \end{document}
    ```

result:

[image]

Comment: Completely awesome. There is an especific reason to put the capacitor current after the simbol?

Comment: Okay @zarko, I have to admit that I do not understood very well your code. I'm trying to make the S1 transistor and the D2 diode with red color, but have not succeed until now.

Comment: to `node [nigbt,anchor=D]  (igbt1) {}` add to option `color=red`, similarly for diode: `to [Do,a=D2] ` add option `color=red`: `to [Do,a=D2,color=red] `

Comment: Yep I did that, but there is an line between the transistor and the label "S2" that stills black

Comment: for coloring of line, you should define their colors as in standard `tikz` pictures, for example for branch with `D2` diode you should write: `draw[red]  (igbt2.S)   -- ++ (0,-0.3) coordinate (D2) to [Do,a=D2,color=red] (D2 -| igbt2.D) -- (igbt2.D);`. i will try to add to answer one more example and some description asap.

Comment: Okay, waiting anxiously.

Comment: To put the current in the right place (before C) is just to write f>^=$i_{C}$ (I don't know how to format code in comments)

Comment: @SrnLord, considered in addendum. thank you very much for the tip.

Comment: @SrnLord, is now answer acceptable to you?

Comment: Your answer is just amazing.

Comment: Such a wonderful suggestion