# Halfbridge IGBT

Tags: graphics, circuitikz

i want to draw a half bridge with IGBT with specific parameter. this is my result so far

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}[straight voltages]  
    
     \draw (0,0) node[anchor=east] {-}
    
       to[short, o-*] (1,0) 
       
    to  node [nigbt,bodydiode](npn){$D_2$} (1,2)
    
     to node [nigbt,bodydiode](npn){$D_1$} (1,4)
     
     to (2,4)--(4,4)
     
     to [capacitor, invert, l=$C_c_c$,v_>=$V_c$,*-*] (4,0)
     
     to(4,0)--(1,0)
    
     (1,2) to[short, -o,i<=$i_c_c$] (0,2) node[anchor=east]{+}

        
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

i would like to have these results

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Could you be a bit more specific about what problem you have?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something from this exapmle [How can I produce this circuit on Latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439536/how-can-i-produce-this-circuit-on-latex)
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    every pin/.style = {pin distance=7mm, inner sep=1pt, text=teal,
        pin edge={teal, line width=2pt, shorten <=-2pt, 
            {Triangle Cap[]}-{Circle[open,line width=1pt,length=1.6mm]}}
    },
}
\ctikzset{resistor = european} %Definição de uso do resitor europeu


\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages,scale=1.25][european resistors]

        \draw
        (0,3) to[open,-*, l_=$V_{1}$] (0,0) %% Criação da Fonte
        ;  %% Finalizando plotagem da fonte


        \draw 
        (0,3) to[L, *-, l^=$L$, f^=$i_{L}$] (3,3) coordinate (Qpos) % conectando um indutor do ponto 0,2 até o 3,2 (Tamanho3)
        (5,3) coordinate (Qpos1)
        (7,3) coordinate (Qpos2)

        (Qpos)++(0,-3)
        to[Tnigbt, bodydiode] ++(0,3)

        (Qpos)        
        to[Tnigbt,bodydiode] ++(3,0)

        (Qpos1)++(1,-3)
        to[C, -,f_<=$i_{C}$,l^=$C_{DC}$] ++(0,3) coordinate (LMpos)

        (Qpos2)++(0.5,-3) coordinate (Rpos)
        to[open,*-*,l_=$V_{2}$] ++(0,3) -- (LMpos) %Se usado o Parametro V<= teriamos o + e - da tensão. Ao contrário disso foi usado l de label

        (Rpos) --(0,0)  
        (3.8,1.5) node[align=center]{$D_1$}
        (2.1,1.5) node[align=center]{$G_1$}
        (4.55,3.8) node[align=center]{$G_2$}
        (4.55,2.4) node[align=center]{$D_2$}
        (0,0) to[short,-*] (3,0)

        ;

    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```